# Linking an object between 2 classes objective c?

Tags: objective-c

I have 2 View Controllers that contain data about an object, which I want to save as a favourite. Both controllers contain the same type of object < Release > which I want to save in a Favourite class.

The Favourite class is fairly simple, it has 3 functions addFavourite, removeFavourite and getFavourites. What I want to accomplish is that both View Controllers can add objects to the Favourite class and get the favouriteObjects array from the Favourite object.

What I tried was making the Favourite class static, like this:

```
@implementation Favourites
static Favourites * favourites = nil;
-(id)init {
 if(favourites == nil) {
  if((favourites = [super init])) {
   return favourites;
  }
 }
 return favourites;
}
@end
```

However, everytime I try to add a favourite from one view controller, it doesn't find it in the other. Anyway to solve this?

Yours Faithfully,
Sem Wong.

If you require more information, please ask, I'm new to this place so I'm not sure how much info you guys need :).

Edit:
Thank you guys for the great answers. I'm trying all of them to see what fits me best. What I've got now seems to work well.

Edit 2:
Seems like I can't upvote anything yet hehe :). Thanks Wain and Lithu T.V and Anum90 for the great answers :).

Comment: what you call *making the Favourite class static* is the attempt to create a singleton. it is not that trivial in objective-c. please search for it, there are plenty of posts about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for the [singleton instance](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html)

How i use it

```
+(Favourites *)sharedInstance
{
    static Favourites*_sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedClient = [[Favourites alloc]init];
    });
    return _sharedClient;

}
```

you can call it in your classes as

```
[Favourites sharedInstance];
```

This will return you an object which is initialised once and return that instance whenever called

Comment: While trying your code, I got an error while trying to write _sharedClient = [[Favourites alloc] init]; that I should try sharedCleint = [[Favourites alloc] init]; instead. Is that what I'm looking for?

Comment: Note that I declare  `static Favourites*_sharedClient = nil;` used that or did you try without underscore?

Answer (score 1):

Try structuring the favourites class like this:

```
@implementation Favourites

- (Favourites *)sharedFavourites
{
static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
__strong static id _sharedObject = nil;
dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
    _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];
});

return _sharedObject;
}

-(id)init {
self = [super init];

return self;
}

@end
```

Then all controllers that need access to the favoutires should call `[Favourites sharedFavourites]` to get the instance (no controller should call `init`).

Comment: Thanks wain, your answer was basically the same as the answer above, which I used to fix it. However your last little info you said about not using init anywhere was a life saver :).

Answer (score -1):

You need to make Favorites a singleton class, that will return one & same instance all the time. After that , you can access this object from anywhere in your project.

```cs
@interface Favourites : NSObject
+(Favourites *)sharedManager;
@end

@implementation Favourites

static Favourites *instance = nil;

+ (Favourites *)sharedManager {

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        if (instance == nil){
            instance = [[self alloc] init];
        }
    });
    return instance;
}

-(id) init
{
    if ( self = [super init] ) {
    }
    return self;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone 
{
   return [self sharedManager];
}

-(void) addFavorite
{
//Do anything or pass any data by making function with argument
}

@end
```

Anywhere, you can call it after importing as,

```cs
[[Favourites sharedManager] addFavorite];
```

If you will call Favourite from anywhere and it has been not allocated before, it will automatically call init and allocate you an object. Every next time you call it, it will return same allocated instance.